# Who is "Mar" ("The Master") in the Bavli?

Tags: rabbis, talmud-bavli, chulin-tractate

Throughout the Bavli, but (based on a Sefaria search) never in the Mishnah, the Tosefta, or the Yerushalmi, we find the phrase "amar Mar" (אמר מר) without any other identifier (in contrast to "Mar Ukva," "Mar bar bar Ashi," and so on).  Amar Mar is translated by Steinsalz as "The Master said." Who is this "Mar"/"Master"? Is there a "stam Mar" the same as there is a "stam Rebbi"? Or could it refer to multiple people? To further confuse matters (or me), sages named "Mar [X]" seem to always be amoraim, but at least in Chullin 94b:2, מר seems to refer to a tanna:

> אמר מר ובעובד כוכבים בין שלימה בין חתוכה אינו צריך ליטול הימנה גיד הנשה במאי עסקינן אילימא במקום שמכריזין חתוכה אמאי אינו צריך ליטול הימנה גיד הנשה כיון דלא אכרוז אתי למיזבן מיניה
>
> **The Master said** in the *baraita*: **And in** the case of one who sends a thigh to **a gentile**, regardless of **whether it is cut or whole he is not required to remove the sciatic nerve from it.** [etc.]

https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.94b.2?lang=bi

First timer here, so please be gentle :)

Comment: https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=17713

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @mbloch Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya, great to have you learning with us and spread Torah! Great question!

According to [this article](https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=17713) it can mean that it is, as Robev mentions, referring to something that has been said earlier one:

> של"ה - כללי התלמוד (יג) כלל לשונות סוגיות:
>
> וההבדל שיש בין 'גופא' ובין 'אמר מר', הוא, כשהביא התלמוד תחילה הענין
> ההוא במקרה, אם להקשות אם לסיוע, אומר אחר כך לשון 'גופא' או לשון 'אמר
> מר'. אבל אם הביא התלמוד איזה ברייתא לא במקרה, אלא בעצם, לא שייך לומר
> אחריה 'גופא', לפי שתיבת 'גופא' יורה שמה שקדם הוא במקרה, וממנו עושה
> עצם.
>
> אבל אם מה שקדם, הוא עצם, לא שייך לומר אחריו 'גופא' אלא 'אמר מר',
>
> כלומר, התנא אומר כך, ויש להקשות כך וכך.

Thus, when the Gemara says "Amar Mar", it is referring to something said in a previous source:

> כלומר, הביטוי "אמר מר" מובא בגמרא במקרה שבו הגמרא מתייחסת לדבר שמוזכר במקור הקודם

It can also be a quote from the Mishnah or a Beraita.

See also this similair [article](https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/brahot/milon-2.htm):

> מונח תלמודי המשמש בתפקיד דומה הוא "אמר מר" [=אמר החכם], אלא
> שקיים בכל זאת הבדל ביניהם: בדרך כלל בסוגיית "אמר מר" הדיון קשור
> יותר לנושא של הסוגיה הקודמת.
> שיטת לימוד להסקת מסקנות מדברי החכמים. לפי שיטה זו חכמים מאוחרים
> דייקו מתוך דבריהם של חכמים שקדמו להם

Comment: Thank you for the response! Here, though, the baraita in its original mention (https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.94a.19?lang=bi) quoted the Sages ("ת"ר השולח ירך לחבירו שלימה") rather than a particular Rabbi. So in my example, do we understand "אמר מר" to refer to the Rabanan? If so, it seems a bit odd to switch from plural to singular, but if that's the accepted standard formula for a previous reference then I can understand why it would be used that way.

Comment: According to my first mentioned article, it can also refer to a beraita, which in this case is.

Answer (score 5):

Amar Mar in the gemarra is a reference to a previous speaker. It is a form of honorific. If you see Amar Mar, it means the gemarra is quoting an earlier phrase. If you look earlier, you'll see who it's referring to.

Answer (score -1):

I was always taught that ‘Mar’ refers to Rabbah. I do not have a source for that other than Gemara teachers of mine, so it’s possible that they meant ‘Mar’ was Rabbah but only the specific Gemara we were learning. If that is the case than one might just have to figure out who ‘Mar’ based on context. If Abaye refers to someone as ‘Mar’, than it is likely Rabbah, but it could be the speaker’s Rebbe.

Comment: If it is the Gemara who calls someone Mar, than I like Robev’s answer.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!